# What is the default working directory when running a mesos chronos command

Tags: docker, mesos, mesos-chronos

I'm interested in figuring out what the default working directory is when a mesos chronos command is run.  For example if I run "java -jar foo/bar/baz.jar" where would the foo directory need to be located in order for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Volume paths or exact paths are not mentioned & assuming you are asking about Mesos Containerizer, I would say it will be on Agent's working directory which can be configured via `--work` parameter. This is per Executor.